# Notification whenever new sheets are added to shared google-drive spreadsheet

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, notifications, sharing, google-drive-sharing

I am using google-drive mostly through Chrome on Linux Ubuntu.
I would like to get notified whenever new sheets are added to a spreadsheet shared by many people.
I've added the notification rule "If form submitted, then send email" already, but this seems to be something different because I wasn't notified last time that new sheets were added.
I am using a Chrome extension to monitor changes on plain websites - that's why I included the information about my browser as well. Maybe such an extension can be used to monitor a spread sheet as well ...

To be clear, I don't want to get notified about every change a user commits to the spreadsheet, only if new sheets are added.